# Uninitialized object? What's wrong with this code.

Tags: c++, object, initialization

For some reason, the code just crashes and gives me an Access Violation error. It keeps saying **the object users is not initialized**.

> First-chance exception at 0x0F45E89A (msvcr110d.dll) in Random Coding
>   in C++.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location
>   0xABABABAB.Unhandled exception at 0x0F45E89A (msvcr110d.dll) in Random
>   Coding in C++.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location
>   0xABABABAB.

Thanks. Any ideas?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct User { 
    string name; //Both first and last name go here 
    int birthYear; 
    string major; 
}; 

int main()
{
    ifstream input("input.txt");

    if(!input || !input.is_open())
        return -1;

    string buffer;
    int count = -1;
    int index = 0;
    int size;
    User* users;

    while(getline(input, buffer, '\n'))
    {
        stringstream ss(buffer);

        if(count == -1)
        {
            ss >> size;
            users = new User[size];
            count = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            if(count == 0)
            {
                users[index].name = buffer;
                count++;
            }
            if(count == 1)
            {
                ss >> users[index].birthYear;
                count++;
            }
            if(count == 2)
            {
                users[index].major = buffer;
                count = 0;
                index++;
            }
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        cout<<users[i].name << " " << users[i].birthYear << " " << users[i].major <<endl;
    }
    system ("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think this is because you are not creating users to populate your array. Whenever you try and access users[index], nothing is there.

Comment: At what point does it crash? Have you debugged it or tracked down the point using simple `cout` traces? Have you considered using a vector instead? Your include path suggests that you have.

Comment: Fill in a `std::cout<<size<<std::endl;` after `ss>>size;`. Might be negative and whatever.

Comment: @user Questions asking to debug a code dump should generally be closed. Instead, please see http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    cout<<users[i].name << " " << users[i].birthYear << " " << users[i].major <<endl;
}
```

Looks incoorect. How are you so sure that users contain atleast two elements. If `getline` fails because of badfile or first line suggests only 1 record, you will get above exception.

You should change the loop to

```
// Initialize size with 0 before while(getline) loop
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    cout<<users[i].name << " " << users[i].birthYear << " " << users[i].major <<endl;
}
```

Also below lines of code look problematic

```
if(count == 0)
{
    users[index].name = buffer;
    count++;
}
if(count == 1)
{
    ss >> users[index].birthYear;
    count++;
}
if(count == 2)
{
    users[index].major = buffer;
    count = 0;
    index++;
}
```

When count is 0, it would go into first if condition and get incremented. Then condition `count == 1` would become true and you will visit next 2 conditions also. You should replace next 2 `if` conditions with `else if` or a `switch` with `break` statements to see the [intended behavior](http://ideone.com/2XyZno).

Also it would be a good practice to free users after you are done with it.

Answer (score 0):

What I think is that the first `getline` fails (the while does not enter, so nothing is created) and you automatically reach the for loop. Check in the for that you actually have users.